# Should I throw generic error in GraphQL Scalar?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to define Scalar types in GraphQL and `graphql-yoga` for server. The problem is I'm trying to decide should I throw `GraphQLError` or just a `TypeError` in this scenario

Currently, I'm using generic Errors.

```js
export const URIScalar = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'URI',
  description: 'A URI whose scheme is \'http\' or \'https\'',
  serialize(value) {
    if (isURI(value)) {
      return value;
    } else {
      throw new Error('URI format is invalid');
    }
  },
  parseValue(value) {
    if (isURI(value)) {
      return value;
    } else {
      throw new Error('URI format is invalid');
    }
  },
  parseLiteral(ast) {
    if (ast.kind === 'StringValue') {
      if (isURI(ast.value)) {
        return ast.value;
      } else {
        throw new Error('URI format is invalid');
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error('URI type must be string');
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Better to create custom errors which make easy to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic errors are perfect, given the information within them are informative.

The client will receive the error as expected, and you'll be able to locate where within your software the error is coming from.

Custom errors are great for when you need more data associated with it, but what you have will work.

Comment: One of the problems, I found that `graphql-yoga` using `apollo-server` in the background, which is it throws errors but also return HTTP 400 for parse and validating GraphQL scalar types. Codes in here https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/3b5735a4ee83af5e35febcc0ff53b01a3f4f0d1b/packages/apollo-server-core/src/runHttpQuery.ts#L298 . Isn't that against GraphQL best practices of not messing up with HTTP code?

Comment: That is expected, this is a validation issue in the end. I have been using this same pattern in apollo-server with zero issues.